# Key not identified in Gitorious

Tags: git, gitorious

I'm triying to push a repository in Gitorious but after some steps when I type git push -u origin master I watch the error:

Permission denied (publickey)
fatal: could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct acess rights and the repository exists.

I check if the key exists and it is because I created it when I create my account.

The repository exists because I created it.

My operating system is Windows 7.

How can I fix it?

Thanks.